# Linq to SQL returning t1 objects based on t1 and t2 criterias

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I want to return all t1 objects and their associated information where its "DeleteFlag" == False, where its associated t2 object's "DeleteFlag" is also False AND t2's "SubmittedFlag" == true.

I want to combine these into one nice Linq to SQL statement, instead I'm currently going the long way of...

```
var record = context.Records.Where(model => model.DeleteFlag == false).Include(model => model.Forms).toList();

    List<Records> returnModel = new List<Records>();

    foreach(var r in record)
    {
       foreach(var f in r.Forms)
       {
           if(f.SubmissionFlag == true && f.DeleteFlag == false)
           {
               returnModel.add(f);
           }
       }
    }
```

with this model I'm possibly loading MANY extra rows on my first db pull AND I'm having to not only iterate through ALL of those extra Record but also the associated Forms until I find my main criteria.

In my mind, it would seem doable in a linq statement kinda like below, but im getting error after error:

```
var records = context.Records.Where(model => model.DeleteFlag == false)
                             .Include(model => model.Forms
                             .Where(form => form.DeleteFlag == false && form.Submissionflag == true)).toList();
```

Any Ideas how to clean up all this recursive work in one nice Linq to SQL statement before I just write a SQL stored proc and call it a day?

Comment: Exactly what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Like this.

```
var records = from record in context.Records
              where !record.DeleteFlag
              from form in record.Forms
              where !form.DeleteFlag && form.Submissionflag
              select form;

return new List<Record>(records);
```

Comment: You should select record, not form

Comment: But the OP is actually adding `Form` into `List<Record>`

Comment: I thought so too, but the question adds f to the list to be returned.  We don't know that it's not also typeof(Record) too.

Comment: I actually came up with a solution right before Ocatviocci posted below with the following code:

`var record = db.Record.Include(model => model.Forms).where(model => model.DeleteFlag == flase && model.Forms.Any(form => form.DeleteFlag == false && form.SubmissionFlag == true)).OrderByDescending(model => model.RecordID).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
var returnModel = context.Records
                         .Where(model => !model.DeleteFlag)
                         .SelectMany(model => model.Forms)
                         .Where(form => !form.DeleteFlag && form.Submissionflag)
                         .ToList();
```